# Helper class to change property of string when serializing for Json.Net

Tags: c#, strings, serialization, json.net

Is there any way to simplify the following C# helper class to numerate a string for Json.Net?

```
internal static string CreateContact(string title)
{
    var createContact = new {Title = title};
    string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(createContact);
    return output;
}

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "9")]
public string Title
{
    get
    {
        return _title;
    }
    set
    {
        _title = value;
        _title = GetTitleId(Title).ToString();
    }
}

public static int? GetTitleId(string title)
{
    //remove "."
    var titleRemoveDots = title.Replace(".", "");
    var titleLowerCase = titleRemoveDots.Trim().ToLower();
    switch(titleLowerCase)
    {
        case "dir":
            return 1;
        case "dr": case "doctor":
            return 4;
        case "mag": case "magister":
            return 5;
        case "ing":
            return 6;
        case "dipling": case "dipl":
            return 7;
        case "prof": case "professor":
            return 8;
        case "dkfm":
            return 9;
        case "prok":
            return 12;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the class named? Is there more to it?

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do in the `Title` setter. First you're assigning `value` to `_title`, then you are assigning the result of `GetTitleId` to `_value`. And you're passing the `Title` property in the method call. Also, I would normally expect the value of a property to have the value I've just set. Finally, the Title property doesn't contain a Title, but contains a TitleId.

Answer (score 4):

Just a quick point, regarding readability; the `switch` block would be better off written like this:

```
//remove "."
var titleRemoveDots = title.Replace(".", "");
var titleLowerCase = titleRemoveDots.Trim().ToLower();
switch(titleLowerCase)
{
    case "dir":
        return 1;
    case "dr": 
    case "doctor":
        return 4;
    case "mag": 
    case "magister":
        return 5;
    case "ing":
        return 6;
    case "dipling": 
    case "dipl":
        return 7;
    case "prof": 
    case "professor":
        return 8;
    case "dkfm":
        return 9;
    case "prok":
        return 12;
    default:
        return null;
}
```

The absence of `break;` between cases (/ the presence of `return` in all cases) can make it harder to refactor the `switch` block later. I think it would be better to separate the concept of *figuring out the return value* and that of *returning a value*:

```
int? result;

//remove "."
var titleRemoveDots = title.Replace(".", "");
var titleLowerCase = titleRemoveDots.Trim().ToLower();
switch(titleLowerCase)
{
    case "dir":
        result = 1;
        break;
    case "dr": 
    case "doctor":
        result = 4;
        break;
    case "mag": 
    case "magister":
        result = 5;
        break;
    case "ing":
        result = 6;
        break;
    case "dipling": 
    case "dipl":
        result = 7;
        break;
    case "prof": 
    case "professor":
        result = 8;
        break;
    case "dkfm":
        result = 9;
        break;
    case "prok":
        result = 12;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

return result;
```

Now, call me a `switch`-hater, I'd probably end up with something like this:

```
public enum PersonTitle
{
    Director = 1,
    Doctor = 4,
    Magister = 5,
    Ingineer = 6,
    Dipling = 7,
    Professor = 8,
    Dkfm = 9, // todo: give readable name
    Prok = 12 // todo: give readable name
}

private static _titleIds = new Dictionary<string, PersonTitle> {
                             { "dir", PersonTitle.Director },
                             { "dr", PersonTitle.Doctor },
                             { "doctor", PersonTitle.Doctor },
                             { "mag", PersonTitle.Magister },
                             { "magister", PersonTitle.Magister },
                             { "ing", PersonTitle.Ingineer },
                             { "dipl", PersonTitle.Dipling },
                             { "dipling", PersonTitle.Dipling },
                             { "prof", PersonTitle.Professor },
                             { "professor", PersonTitle.Professor },
                             { "dkfm", PersonTitle.Dkfm },
                             { "prok", PersonTitle.Prok }
                         };
```

And then `GetTitleId` could look like this:

```
public static int? GetTitleId(string title)
{
    var cleanTitle = title.Replace(".", string.Empty).Trim().ToLower();
    PersonTitle result;

    if (_titleIds.TryGetValue(cleanTitle, out result))
    {
        return (int)result;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

One issue is that `Title` is actually a `string` representation of the `int` value, which can be allowed to be `null` - I might be mistaken, but it looks like the setter for `Title` would throw a `NullReferenceException` if/when that is the case, because it's calling `ToString()` on `null`:

> ```
> [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "9")]
> public string Title
> {
>     get
>     {
>         return _title;
>     }
>     set
>     {
>         _title = value;
>         _title = GetTitleId(Title).ToString();
>     }
> }
> ```

I'd expect a null-check there:

```
 set
 {
     _title = value;
     _title = (GetTitleId(Title) ?? string.Empty).ToString();
 }
```

Comment: If anything this code is more complex than the code in my original question.

Comment: @user2151345 indeed, a `switch` block with hard-coded magic numbers and strings is simpler *to code*. I find the dictionary simpler *to maintain*.